# Active Directory - forest trust between forests with same name?

Tags: windows, active-directory

lets say there are two AD forests which by coincidence happen to have same name, for example "foo.local". Is it possible to establish a trust relationship between such forests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really doubt it, but more to the point, I'd **strongly** recommend against it. Even if technically it works it's going to be so horrendously confusing to diagnose issues that I would never even entertain the idea.

Comment: Have to agree. I really can't see this working. For a start, just imagine the potential confusion in DNS namespace.

Comment: I agree that DNS is the main issue here. Any way to overcome it?